# Transition effect on before element

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to get the "Book an Appointment" button to work on this website https://templates.hibootstrap.com/arrola/default/index-2.html. I have the following css

```
.appointmentButton:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.appointmentButton {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: $black1;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover:before {
    background-color: $greenColor;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

and the html element:
`<a className={styles.appointmentButton} href="/appointment">Book an Apppointment</a>`.
I'm trying to get the button background colour to change to green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appointmentButton add display: inline block

```css
.appointmentButton {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #191f30;
  display: inline-block;
}
  .appointmentButton::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background-color: #72ae44;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
 .appointmentButton:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<a class="appointmentButton" href="/appointment">Book an Apppointment</a>
```